# sankey-diagram (skip column) highcharts

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I'm implementing a Sankey Diagram using the Highcharts JS and I'm trying to put a line that accesses the first column for the third column. It is possible?
For example: jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/18 In that case, I'm trying to put a line from Brazil to Germany, but do not move Germany to the second column.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/20/ If not, please elaborate on your question because it is unclear in that case.

Comment: Oh great! hahaha I didn't know that the order modify the graph! thanks! hahahha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the data is of importance when wanting to connect the first to the third column. As shown in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/25/) JSFiddle, Germany will move to the second column if the data is shown like this:

```
 data: [
            ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 2 ],
            ['Brazil', 'Germany', 3], //Here won't work
            ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
            ['Canada', 'France', 1 ],
            ['USA', 'England', 4 ],
            ['England', 'Germany', 3]
        ],
```

However, when we move the Brazil-Germany connection to the bottom, it will show the expected behavior:

```
    data: [
        ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 2 ],       
        ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Canada', 'France', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'England', 4 ],
        ['England', 'Germany', 3],
        ['Brazil', 'Germany', 3] //Here will work
    ],
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/morn2e4g/20/)